# jQuery File Upload: cURL file uploads working, Python requests not

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to figure out the cause of this issue. I am using `requests` to POST files using the file uploader https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to send the POSTs

Running this on my CLI works perfectly fine:

```
curl -F "files=@test.txt" https://example.com/jqu/index.php
```

And returns:

```
{
   "files":[
      {
         "name":"61a250036a881080db16a00827d41d53.txt",
         "size":2,
         "type":"text\/plain",
         "niceSize":"2 B",
         "realName":"test.txt",
         "delFileKey":"4d88ea9cced859c521927d3725710518",
         "fileKey":"f804e7d6214d16212c03dcde176102ba",
         "delete_url":"https:\/\/example.com\/jqu\/?file=61a250036a881080db16a00827d41d53.txt",
         "delete_type":"DELETE"
      }
   ]
}
```

Trying the same thing in `requests` is failing:

```py
files = {
    'files': ('test.txt', open('test.txt', 'rb')),
}

upload = requests.post('https://example.com/jqu/index.php', files=files).json()
```

```
{
   'error':"File wasn't successfully moved/upped.",
   'size':False,
   'niceSize':'0 B',
   'delete_url':'https://example.com/jqu/?file=85f2023603e8dc9bbee557b80f4cd779.',
   'name':'85f2023603e8dc9bbee557b80f4cd779.',
   'type':'multipart/form-data',
   'delete_type':'DELETE',
   'realName':None
}
```

Any ideas as to why it's working in cURL but failing in `requests`? Any help is much appreciated, I'm stumped here.

Comment: you need to define the contentType:false in the options of the request and also I don't think converting your object to json will work. just send the object directly but don't converting it to json.

Comment: @BlackXero I did both these things. `headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'false'
    }
    uploader = requests.post('https://example.com/jqu/index.php', headers=headers, files=files)`

Still getting the same issue. Any idea what else could be going wrong?